# Grafana grouping to matrix by timestamp

Tags: grafana, victoriametrics, grafana-dashboard

I am using Grafana and trying to create a pivot using the timestamp as column.

[image]

The first Panel shows the row data (I don't have much data yet). They are aggregated by week and the information that I need are the resname, value, and timestamp.

The second image shows the data as a table.

The third image shows the result I want to obtain, with the exception that the column name is epoch and not a timestamp.
I want to show as the first column the resname. The other columns should be the day (aggregated already to weeks) in an ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD).

Is there a way to achieve what I want, and convert the column name from epoch to a timestamp string?

Thanks,
Simone

Comment: This looks more like a question about Grafana. See more about how to convert time to the needed format here https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-convert-timestamp-and-then-group-by-date/65948/12